# jQuery: while mouse is down continuously enact event, when mouse up turn off event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a code that when executed upon holding down mouse click will

1. let mouse enter execute fadeTo function making div disappear
2. when mouse is up it will turn off fadeTo function

   ```
   $('div').mousedown(function () {
         $('div').mouseenter(function(){ 
             $(this).fadeTo('fast',0);
   });
   ```

How do I make above code continuously execute while mouse is pressed and also how do I make above code do nothing while mouse is up?

Thanks in advance! - noobie

Comment: when you say turn off fadeTo function you mean return to normal or stop where it is?

Comment: Don't day "- noobie". Correct spelling and grammar instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have it fade while clicking is to reduce the opacity bit by bit while the mouse is down.

```js
var op = 1;
$('div').mousedown(function() {
 var d=$(this);
  timeout = setInterval(function() {        
    d.fadeTo('fast', op);
    op -= .03;
  }, 125);
  return false;
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Click me and see me fade, stop clicking and I'll stop fading.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved solution:

```
        var down = false;

  $(document).mousedown(function () {
      down = true;
  }).mouseup(function(){
      down = false;
  });

  $('div').mouseover(function(){
    if(isdown){
      $(this).fadeTo('fast',0)
    }
  });
```